Outdoor porch concrete slab, step riser bowed line 1/2" what do I use to fill the gap when installing outdoor tiles
Below is the picture that worths 1000 words
The gap is like 1/2" at max. Do I need a stronger mortar or thin set modified mortar will hold here


As RMDman wrote add more behind it the tiles. Most tiles will adhere to the surface by applying the thinset to surface only and not the tile, well, maybe with a "scratch coat" on the tile only, it prompotes better adhesion. In the middle, the scratch coat will need to be a coat like that what is on the surface, called "double buttering" That may be enough to get you straight like you need. In some larger gaps, you may need to add dabs of thinset here and there to fill the remaining voids.  DO NOT ADD TOO MUCH!! This is on top of the double buttering, adding to it..

That is filled with the thin set you use. Just add a bit more to help fill the gap.
